# Unable to get scalar value of a query on cosmos db in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am trying to get the count of all records present in cosmos db in a lookup activity of azure data factory. I need this value to do a comparison with other value activity outputs.

The query I used is `SELECT VALUE count(1) from c`

When I try to preview the data after inserting this query I get an error saying

```
One or more errors occurred. Unable to cast object of type  
 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'
```

as shown in the below image:
[snapshot of my azure lookup activity settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WQLe.png)

Could someone help me in resolving this error and if this is the limitation of azure data factory how can I get the count of all the rows of the cosmos db document using some other ways inside azure data factory?

Comment: Surya, may you enrich your question with tests performed in both Azure portal's Data Explorer and SDK? perhaps how did you struct your "c" container? A reference in case you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-aggregates

Comment: Rafael, When I run the same query in Azure portal's Data explorer I get proper value[Example: 35000].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce your issue on my side exactly.

[image]

I think the count result can't be mapped as normal JsonObject. As workaround,i think you could just use Azure Function Activity(Inside Azure Function method ,you could use SDK to execute any sql as you want) to output your desired result: `{"number":10}`.Then bind the Azure Function Activity with other activities in ADF.

---

Here is contradiction right now:

The query sql outputs a scalar array,not other things like jsonObject,or even jsonstring.

[image]

However, ADF Look Up Activity only accepts JObject,not JValue. I can't use any convert built-in function here because the query sql need to be produced with correct syntax anyway. I already submitted a ticket to MS support team,but get no luck with this limitation.

[image]

I also tried `select count(1) as num from c` which works in the cosmos db portal. But it still has limitation because the sql crosses partitions.

[image]

So,all i can do here is trying to explain the root cause of issue,but can't change the product behaviours.

2 rough ideas:

1.Try no-partitioned collection to execute above sql to produce json output.

2.If the count is not large,try to query columns from db and loop the result with ForEach Activity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I cannot use Azure function activity in my organization.

Comment: @Surya You're welcome. Please see my update answer . Thx.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this is a limitation. I tried setting a variable after performing a count but it seems like there is a limitation of 5000 in the lookup so this is also not viable. I think we can't do anything else except wait for Microsoft to lift up the limitations or add features to accept JValue as output.

Comment: @Surya Yes,i know that 5000 limitation. Anyway, loop is a rough idea i think...sorry....

Comment: @Surya Yeah,feel frustrated about this bottleneck so far.Maybe you could submit feedback to ADF team to push progress here.I have another idea that is using Azure Function Activity in ADF. If you know Azure Function,it could be used for any Flexible requirements. You could just execute normal cosmos db sql inside azure function and access the output of Azure Function Activity in ADF then use it in the next step. This is the most appropriate solution for you right now,per my knowledge.

Comment: @Surya Anyway,if the workaround is acceptable,you could accept this answer for others' reference who met the same bottleneck.Thank you in advance.If i got any updates of this limitation,i will post updates here to @ you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 select top 1 column from c order by column desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue recently and I was able to get the count assigned to an alias (and thus be read as a JObject for Data Factory) by doing the query this way

```
SELECT num FROM (SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c) as num
```